# CMS for Software introducing

Tags: web-applications, open-source, web, software-distribution

I'm looking for a CMS designed to introduce software. I want be able to

1. Describe my software
2. Show Screenshots
3. Publish News
4. upload the newes package, so everyone can download it.

Until now I used WP, but point 4 is not realy supportet.

Further it would be great if users could open bug-tickes etc.

Perhaps something that looks a bit like SourceForge etc. would be great, but I want to run it on my own server.

It should run with php and MySQLor SQLite, since I don't have root acces to my server.

**A little Edit for the close voters:**

> but if your question generally covers
>
> - ...
> - software tools commonly used by programmers

from the StackOverflow FAQ. IMHO this is a question about `software tools commonly used by programmers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Ruby on Rails, I would suggest [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) and [ClockingIT](http://www.clockingit.com/).

Otherwise, I know two very simple CMS that could do that, but you would have to work a bit to create a bug and ticket system.

- [SilverStripe CMS](http://silverstripe.org/)
- [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try out http://trac.edgewall.org/

Comment: I know trac, but it doesn't run with php ;-)